# Ajax удаляет переносы строк

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
<script>
    $("#send_post").click(function(){
        var text = document.getElementById("txt_post").value;

        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '/request/profile/send_post?text='+text,

            success: function(jsondata){

                if (jsondata.send == 'true') {
                    ////
                } else {
                    ////
                }

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

В форме ввода содержится текст с переводом строки:

> Text Text Text
>
> Text Text Text

Но в обработчик приходит

> Text Text TextText Text Text

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дайте библиотеке возможность закодировать данные для отправки.

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: 'json',
  url: '/request/profile/send_post,
  data: { text: text },
  ...
```

Comment: Проблема решена, но частично. Перенос передается, но только один. Но если в тексте два и более перевода строки, то они не передаются